# Взаимодействие с внешними консольными приложеними. (С++)

Tags: c++

Есть вопрос, как взаимодействовать со внешними прилженими? Есть приложение A и консольное проложение B. Вопрос, как из приложения А запустить приложение B передать ему параметры, дождаться ответа, то есть отловить возвращаемое консольным приложением B значение.

Comment: А чем плох spawn? Ну или exec.

Comment: Уточните, вам кроссплатформенно нужно или под конкретную ось? Используете ли какой-либо фреймворк наподобие QT?

Comment: Для Ваших целей есть специально обученная функция: `popen()` (в мире MS известна как `_popen()/_wpopen()`). Позволяет запустить приложение и "общаться" с ним, через стандартные потоки ввода/вывода. Подробнее можно почитать: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/96ayss4b.aspx или http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=popen&category=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея состоит в том, что у приложения есть три потока ввода-вывода

```
stdin
stdout
stderr
```

эти потоки можно подхватить из своего приложения и тогда запись и чтение в них будет эквивалентна ручному вводу и чтению вывода из приложения.

Если вы используете `Qt`, все становится совсем просто, потому как там внешний процесс можно будет запустить через `QProcess`, который является наследником `QIODevice`, что позволяет просто писать и читать в этот `QIODevice`

[Пример реализации](https://github.com/BG4444/PingerExample)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вызвать коммандный процессор (/bin/bash или cmd.exe) из приложения A через `std::system`, передав комманду запуска приложения B в виде строки.

А чтобы получить вывод приложении А можно перенаправить вывод B в файл, затем прочитать этот файл стандартныйми средствами

Пример для unix подобных систем:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::system("ls -l > test.txt"); // execute the UNIX command "ls -l >test.txt"
    std::cout << std::ifstream("test.txt").rdbuf();
}
```